# Is there a way to add multiple messages to postMessage on the same iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe that is a form. The iframe needs to grab some url params from the parent window and add them to some hidden fields.

Currently on the source domain I have this:

```
var iframe = $('iframe[src^="DOMAIN"]'),
src = iframe.attr('src'),
data = window.location.search,
destination = iframe.get(0).contentWindow;

destination.postMessage(data, src);
```

And on the iframe/other domain I have this, plus a function for filling the form inputs:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ?
    "addEventListener" :
    "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent" ?
    "onmessage" :
    "message";
  eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    $('#output').text(e.data);
  });
```

The issue is that there is something else being use on the site (iframe resizer) that is using the same `contentWindow` on the same iframe.

I think the data is getting overwritten because `e.data` is showing *[iFrameSizer]iFrameResizer0:8:false:false:...* when I would expect *?utm_campain=test...*

Is there a way to use the same or a different object property to send/receive a message?

Answer (score 0):

You could send an object and check properties of the object to know that is the message you want to work with:

You probably also want to check the source is the parent window

Something like:

```
var iframe = $('iframe[src^="DOMAIN"]'),
src = iframe.attr('src'),
data = {searchParams: window.location.search},
destination = iframe.get(0).contentWindow;

destination.postMessage(data, src);
```

In frame:

```
eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    if(e.source !== window.parent){
      console.log('Messaage not from parent');
      return;
    }

   if(typeof e.data === 'object' && e.data.hasOwnProperty('searchParams') ){
       $('#output').text(e.data.searchParams);
   }
});
```